# Sublime Text 3 Output Python

Tags: python, configuration, output, sublimetext3

I work on two computers, I have Sublime Text 3 and Python 2.7 on both of them.

Recently, without changing any configuration (except maybe installing some packages like ANACONDA for ST3), when I build my python code on Sublime Text 3: e.g.,

```
print 'Hello world'
```

Console output is just showing:

```
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

And nothing more, (I want to see the printed text), this is quite irritating because for the life of me I can't figure out how to solve this.

A related and perhaps identical problem is experienced by @Jens_Leersen.
I've tried the answer contained in @radioxoma 's answer but to no avail.

[Related example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144050/5006869)

Comment: Is the directory containing the `python` executable in your `PATH`? Did you choose the Python build system before building? Are there any errors or messages in the console?

Comment: Yes, the python exec. is in the `PATH` defined in the environment variables. and yes I chose python on the build system. No errors just the message `[Finished in 0.1s]`
Example of a program with multiple prints
[link](http://imgur.com/P6xdZNh)

Comment: How did you start Sublime - double-clicking on an icon, or from the command line? Also, when you build, does a black window open up, then immediately close?

Comment: I start Sublime by clicking on my quick access icon in the taskbar, when I build no black window opens up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed by uninstalling `python 2.7`, and installing Anaconda with python 3.5, then installing anaconda through `Package Control`.

Answer (score 1):

I got that thing as well. You can change it by Tools/Build with and choose "Python" instead of "Python- Syntax Check". It turns out that I clicked "Syntax Check" the first time I try to compile. My dumb mistake costs me a few minutes of panic.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+shift+b this will show a box asking you if you want to use Python or Python Syntax Check. Select Python and once you are done you will be able to use Ctrl+b to build you code and see the output at the bottom. this answer is just about the same as @1757 answers right below i am just using shortcuts to get to the same functionality

Thank you @1757

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, press ctrl + shift + b and click on python (not python - syntax check).
Build and Voila!